# SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Tags: php, localhost

> 2018-03-05 18:25:08 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP
>   o5sm27821483pfh.51 - gsmtp 2018-03-05 18:25:08 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO
>   localhost 2018-03-05 18:25:08 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at
>   your service, [43.247.156.6]250-SIZE
>   35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250
>   SMTPUTF8 2018-03-05 18:25:08 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS 2018-03-05
>   18:25:08 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS SMTP Error:
>   Could not connect to SMTP host. 2018-03-05 18:25:09 CLIENT -> SERVER:
>   QUIT 2018-03-05 18:25:09  2018-03-05 18:25:09  SMTP connect() failed.
>   https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting Message
>   has been sent

my code is

```
<?php
// Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
// These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

//Load composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';



$mail = new PHPMailer();                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'girish8134@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = '*****';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('girish8134@gmail.com', 'Giri');
    $mail->addAddress('girish3055@gmail.com', 'giri3055');     // Add a recipient


    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message bod';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body is';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Comment: I am trying send and email from localhost using gmail.
Note:Composer has been installed successfully.

Answer (score 1):

first try this> https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1064203?hl=en
Disabling two step authentication.

If it doesn't work like that, you can always try and simplify some code (and try `ssl - port 467`):

```
$mail->setFrom('girish8134@gmail.com');
$mail->addAddress('girish3055@gmail.com');
```

Let me know if it worked.

Comment: thanks for your help,
1)2 step authentication is off.
2)  now I am getting 
"Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\maildemo\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\SMTP.php on line 1270"  , after changing port to 467 and ssl.
Note : I changed timeout to 1 min even then its not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';       // Use SSL encryption,
$mail->Port = 465                // change port to 465
```